# python exec docker-compose up never blocking in pull images

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, subprocess

I have a project which need exec docker-compose command by python. I type `subprocess.getoutput("docker-compose up -d")` to exec it.

But this will block the `main process` because the associated `images` need to be `pull` first. I don't want it to block the `main process` and not require its execution results. I use `&` in `command`, such as `subprocess.getoutput("docker-compose up -d &")`. But it didn't seem to work.

How do I achieve my goal which is to execute the docker-compose up command using python non-blocking?

Comment: You want to run a particular container(subprocess) using docker exec -it container_id ?

Comment: @Mukesh yes, the main process is actually in a docker container which uses the external `docker.sock`. I execute the python command in the docker container to run `docker-compose up`, which actually launches compose on the host machine.

Comment: `getoutput()` is a blocking command. If you use `Popen()` it won't block.